# How to use CombineLatest in Rx.NET for 2 different types

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, rx.net, combinelatest

I cant work out what the syntax is to combine these two observables, property `Configuration` and `BalanceDtos` in Rx.NET, can do it in RxJS no problem (example below), any ideas?  This is as close as I can get it, but its not correct.

```
public IObservable<Subroutine> Configuration { get; set; }

    public List<IObservable<List<OtherObject>>> BalanceDtos { get; set; }

    public IObservable<List<OtherObject>> GetSubRoutinesTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return Observable.CombineLatest(Configuration, BalanceDtos.CombineLatest()).Select((config, bals) =>
            {
                Subroutine test1 = config; //these are the objects that I want coming out of this CombineLatest observable.
                List<OtherObject> test2 = bals;
            });
        }
    }
```

So what I want is when either the property Configuration observable changes, or any of the observables in the BalanceDto property change it should emit that change

Marbles would be:

```
-c1-b1-b2-b3-c2
---[c1,b1]-[c1,b2]-[c1-b3]-[c2,b3]
```

With RxJS in typescript I would write the following:

```
let obsArray$: Observable<Subroutine>;
   let otherModel$: Observable<OtherObject>[];
   combineLatest([obsArray$, combineLatest(otherModel$)]).subscribe(([obsArray, otherModel]) => {
       let test1: Subroutine = obsArray;
       let tes2: OtherObject[] = otherModel;
   });
```

I just cant work out what the syntax is for the same thing in Rx.NET. I have looked at other examples for Rx.NET `CombineLatest`, but they always combine objects of the same type.

Comment: Could you provide sample input and output, as a marble diagram `+--1---2---3--|` or other way, or describe how the observable and the `List` of observables should be combined?

Comment: Updated to add comment to question, thanks!

Comment: I am a bit confused with the marble diagram. Shouldn't include two source sequences, and a third one with the results? (like [this](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html))

Comment: Your not comparing apples with apples here, your rxjs are flat observables with one of those observables being an array of values where as you .Net example contains a list of observables `List<IObservable<List<OBJ2>>> BalanceDtos`, the the js equivalent would be `Observable<OtherObject>[];` . given that it's not really clear what exactly your expecting and the "marble diagram" doesn't really help

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question so the Rx.NET and RxJS examples are operating on the same object types.  Hopefully this makes it clearer what I am trying to achive.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to do this now, here is the solution:

```
public IObservable<Subroutine> Configuration { get; set; }

    public List<IObservable<List<OtherObject>>> BalanceDtos { get; set; }

    public IObservable<List<OtherObject>> GetSubRoutinesTotal
    {
        get
        {
           return BalanceDtos.CombineLatest().CombineLatest(Configuration, (bals, config) =>
            {
                Subroutine test1 = config; //these are the objects that I want coming out of this CombineLatest observable.
                IList<List<OtherObject>> test2 = bals;
                return test2[0];
            });
        }
    }
```